# Sorry, there's nothing at this address page displaying when i clicked on the link using C# Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor

I am trying to learn Blazor following youtube tuturial. I want to display the list of student using the code below. When I clicked on the student link I have "Sorry, there's nothing at this address." please can anyone tell me where I am going wrong

NavBar

```
    <li class="nav-item px-3">
        <NavLink class="nav-link" href="Pages/Student">
            <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> Student data
        </NavLink>
    </li>
```

Student Controller

```
    public class StudentController : ControllerBase
    {
    private readonly RazorExampleContext _context;

    public StudentController(RazorExampleContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    // GET: api/Student
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<List<Student>>> GetStudent()
    {
        return await _context.Student.ToListAsync();
    }
   }
```

RaZor Page

```
 @page "/Student"
 @inject HttpClient Http
  // Display student list    
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Student Id</th>
            <th>Student Name</th>               
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var student in students)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>

                <a class="btn btn-success" href="Student/">Edit</a>
                <button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>

            </td>
            <td>student.Id</td>
            <td>student.StudentName</td>
        </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
   </table>
  }
  @code {
       Student[] students { get; set; }
   protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
   {
       await LoadStudent();
   }
  async Task LoadStudent()
  {
    students = await Http.GetJsonAsync<Student[]>("api/Student");
  }

 }
```

Startup.cs

```
 // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddServerSideBlazor();
        services.AddHttpClient();
        services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
        services.AddSingleton<Student>();
    }
```

Comment: `@page "/Pages/Student"` for `href="/Pages/Student">` . Btw, learn about [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @dani don't understand what you want me to do please

Comment: `Sorry, there's nothing at this address` with Blazor could be `Progressive Web Application` due to the `serviceWorker`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67506395/3850405

Comment: Assuming your href matches your @page definition, if you still get that error, try redirecting with    NavManager.NavigateTo("Pages/Student", new NavigationOptions { ForceLoad = true });

Answer (score 5):

This error usually occurs when the Router cannot find the url address provided to it. Change This : `<NavLink class="nav-link" href="Pages/Student">`
to `<NavLink class="nav-link" href="student">`

Not related to the answer:

- Why do you do this: `services.AddSingleton<Student>();` Student is your model, not a service you're going to inject into your components
- You should verify that the Student array is populated with data before you use it in the foreach loop, otherwise a null reference exception is triggered.
- The route template should be  @page "/student" and not  @page "/Student" by convention.

Comment: Thanks for your reply I did the change you requested but now I am having the error "InvalidOperationException: Cannot provide a value for property 'Http' on type 'StudentProject.Pages.Student.Student'. There is no registered service of type 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient'."

Comment: In my case the problem was that by .blazor file had Build Action set to "None" instead of "Content" for some strange reason. I changed it to "Content" and it worked

Comment: @HugoNavaKopp I had that same issue here. It should be a possible answer for this question.

Comment: @HugoNavaKopp why not post this as answer? you are correct

Comment: @toha yes thanks, but unfortunately the question is closed now :-(